# gulp annotate error when building AngularJS template

Tags: angularjs, node.js, gulp

I'm new to gulp and node is not my backyard either so I'd need some help finding out what the problem is when I build a template form [StartAngular](https://startangular.com/product/versatile-angularjs-theme/).

I have downloaded the template and following the instructions in the readme to build it (I'm on a Mac with Sierra and brew) I run into the following error running `gulp build`:

```
(node:13596) DeprecationWarning: process.EventEmitter is deprecated. Use require('events') instead.
[15:28:55] Starting 'clean'...
[15:28:56] Finished 'clean' after 20 ms
[15:28:56] Starting 'build'...
[15:28:56] Starting 'jshint'...
[15:28:56] Starting 'styles'...
[15:28:56] Starting 'images'...
[15:28:56] Starting 'fonts'...
[15:28:56] Starting 'extras'...
[15:28:56] Finished 'build' after 822 ms
[15:28:57] Finished 'jshint' after 1.15 s
[15:28:57] Finished 'images' after 407 ms
[15:28:58] Finished 'styles' after 1.82 s
[15:28:58] Starting 'html'...
[15:28:58] Finished 'extras' after 1.89 s

events.js:160
    throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
    ^
Error: styles/main.css: error: couldn't process source due to parse 
error
Unexpected character '@' (1:0)
```

#### Tried so far

I have opened an issue [here](https://github.com/start-angular/versatile-dashboard-theme/issues/9) and I see that the template code is 2 years old and it's clear there are version issues causing this problem.

I have tried with node 4, 6 and 7 and also forcing the bower and npm dependencies to the minimum versions in the `{package,bower}.json` files without any success.

I have also looked into `.tmp` and I see `styles/main.css` there and it looks fine and indeed starts with the `@` which should be fine.

I have also edited `app/index.html` to bit by bit comment out the failing parts because after this error I get several other issues related to stuff like so:

```
<!-- build:css(.tmp) styles/vendor.css -->
<!-- bower:css -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/fontawesome/css/font-awesome.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../bower_components/angular-snap/angular-snap.css" />
<!-- endbower -->
```

Commenting out all these will of course not solve things but it just shows that all these similar directives fail for `.js` and `.css`.

I've also looked into `gulpfile.js` to try to understand what is going on but nothing enlightening so far.

Google also seems to give all kinds of suggestions under the sun which I tried a few without success and it's not clear what part really fails either.

I'd like to get this template to work so and make a PR to fix things and I'd appreciate any help form you here :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was broken regexs, a patch looks like this:

```
diff --git a/gulpfile.js b/gulpfile.js
index 3fbadef..d19cd08 100644
--- a/gulpfile.js
+++ b/gulpfile.js
@@ -36,12 +36,12 @@ gulp.task('html', ['styles'], function() {

   return gulp.src('app/**/*.html')
     .pipe(assets)
-    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.ngAnnotate()))
-    .pipe($.if('*.js', $.uglify()))
-    .pipe($.if('*.css', cssChannel()))
+    .pipe($.if('.*\.js', $.ngAnnotate()))
+    .pipe($.if('.*\.js', $.uglify()))
+    .pipe($.if('.*\.css', cssChannel()))
     .pipe(assets.restore())
     .pipe($.useref())
-    .pipe($.if('*.html', $.htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true})))
+    .pipe($.if('.*\.html', $.htmlmin({collapseWhitespace: true})))
     .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
 });
```